Installation of ubuntu in ssd or migration to ssd from hdd
Good morning!
I’m experiencing difficulties installing Ubuntu on my SSD. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
Partitioning:
Created two partitions:
First partition: EFI type, FAT32
Second partition: Data and system type, ext4
Cloning:
Attempted to clone an existing installation, but it didn’t work.
Creating Installation Media:
Downloaded the official Ubuntu ISO.
Used dd to create a bootable installation media.
Booting:
Selected the installation media to boot from, but it doesn’t work as expected.
Questions:
Am I missing any steps in the installation process?
Are there additional steps required to ensure a successful installation?
Thank you for your assistance!

If you want to just install Ubuntu to the ssd you need to create usb, you can use BalenaEtcher https://etcher.balena.io/, then best it is to disconnect your hdd and only have your ssd and just go through installation, use Erase disk and install ubuntu if you want it easy, refer to this https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#6-type-of-installation

How did you attempt to clone. Did that erase your partitions, do then installer cannot see drive?

The first time the clone juste cloned the sda6 of hdd which has linux on it then created one partition which taken all the space.Is there a way to complete this process which i started? Like a have two partitions efi fat32 and for system and data ext4? And i have an iso on the ssd with the dd command as a media bootable? Thank you!

I think you’re really complicating things by trying to clone an existing installation. Far easier to create installation USB media and perform a proper install.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Can you please show me how to install it on the ssd using the hdd principal disk??Thank you
